# String with multiple lines of weblink images. How to display them?

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I've got a String full of weblink image (23 links) :

```
listItem.text = String(item.movieimage);
```

If I do trace(String(item.movieimage)); the output is :

```
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/xxx_3.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/vaiana.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/tous_scene.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/fits.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/boyfriend.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/sahara2017.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/resident_evil_final.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/raid_dingue.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/passengers2017.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/lego_batman.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/grande_muraille.jpg
http://www.thewebsite.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/fille_brest.jpg
```

Know, I've got 9 UILoader on my stage.

So I would like to do

```
uiloader1.source = item.movieimage[1];
uiloader2.source = item.movieimage[2];
uiloader3.source = item.movieimage[3];
```

...etc...

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of such a "weblink image"? What's wrong with [**first page**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=as3+load+image) of google results? What's wrong with the manual's [**example**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo)?... You need to **show code of what you've tried** so we can help you fix it. Otherwise find a tutorial online via web search.

Comment: I've edited my post with more explanation. You were right, it wasn't very clear. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're separated by an indent

```
//Put all the links in an array
var myItems:Array = listItem_txt.text.split("\n");

//You say you only have nine, so only iterate until the 9th
for (var i:int = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    //Also assuming your "uiloader" is a custom class you made with a .source property
    this.getChildByName("uiloader" + i).source = myItems[i];
}
```